# Некорректное оторбажение данных из бд

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня имеется база данных,содержащие списки товаров купленных конкретными пользователями,и у меня есть 1 пользователь купивший 3 разных товара,но когда я отображаю это в ListBox выводится 3 одинаковый заказа,место 3 разных,отладчиком проходился в коллекции 3 идентичных элемента,прошу помочь

VM

```
public ObservableCollection<PurchaseHistory> ItemsForPurchaseHistoryBox { get; set; }
public UserPurchasesHistoryWindowVm()
        {
            
            UserContext context = new UserContext();
 
            ItemsForPurchaseHistoryBox = new ObservableCollection<PurchaseHistory>(context.PurchasesSet.Where(us => us.LoginOfBuyer == LoginNamespace.Logins.login));
 
        }
```

Одно из полей в таблице Purchasehistory,ищу этот логин по логину кто вошел в систему

```
LoginOfBuyer
```

Специальный класс,который хранит логин того кто вошел в систему

```
LoginNamespace.Logins.login
```

Context

```
class UserContext:DbContext
    {
        public UserContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
 
        }
 
        public DbSet<PurchaseHistory> PurchasesSet { get; set; }
 
    }
```

View

```
<WpfApp1:ContextHolder Margin="-112,0,9.6,10">
            <WpfApp1:ContextHolder.Commands >
                <WpfApp1:CommandBinding RoutedCommand="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}"
                                      RelayCommand="{Binding ShowСhequeOfProductCommand}"/>
 
            </WpfApp1:ContextHolder.Commands>
            <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForPurchaseHistoryBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="394" Margin="34,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="358">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Mod:PurchaseHistory}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Название товара" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding NameOfBoughtProduct}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </DockPanel>
                                <Button Margin="5"  Content="Просмотреть чек" 
                                    Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </WpfApp1:ContextHolder>
```

[image: _]

[image: _]

Comment: `отладчиком проходился в коллекции 3 идентичных элемента` - если вы выяснили источник проблемы, то к чему тогда здесь WPF, коллекции, привязки? Разбирайтесь тогда, почему `context.PurchasesSet.Where(us => us.LoginOfBuyer == LoginNamespace.Logins.login)` выдает вам 3 одинаковых объекта.

Comment: А разве не за этим я обратился на этот форум,чтобы задать вопрос,так как здесь есть люди разбирающиеся в данной области лучше чем я,для которых что-то будет очевидным,а для меня нет

Comment: Во-первых, это не форум, а ресурс, где сообщество собирает полезную информацию не только для автора вопроса, но и для всего сообщества в целом, включая будущих читателей, уважайте пожалуйста это. Во-вторых, ваш вопрос акцентирует внимание на WPF, MVVM, привязки, когда проблема с вашей неведомой базой, о который вы нам и слова не сказали, мы видим лишь запрос, но что это? EF? В-третьих, если вы напишете `var result = new string[] { "Вася", "Вася"}.Where(x=>x == "Вася")`, то что вам даст в итоге? Наверно 2 "Вася", ибо их 2 в массиве, так может у вас в базе 3 идентичные записи? Нам то не знать...

Comment: Вы пишете то что я и так знаю,и я написал про базу данных в вопросе,у меня в ней 3 элемента,но они разные и ваш пример про "Васю" неуместен здесь
В бд у меня 3 записи,и я осуществляю поиск по логину того кто вошел, и логу в бд,сибда я обратился потому что такой ситуации со мной не было до этого

Comment: Вы меня не слышите, я вам говорю, что из вопроса стоит убрать все лишнее, убрать разметку, убрать WPF, убрать привязки, оставить только LINQ запрос, ибо сейчас ваш вопрос выглядит так, будто во всем виновата коллекция, которая привязана к ListBox... Также еще раз повторю, если вопрос про базу, то дайте больше информации, что за база, какие там данные, не знаю, приложите скрин, где в отладке вы видите нужные данные, но запрос их не берет. Вот встаньте на наше место, вам дают лишь `.Where(x=>x == "Вася")` и говорят "почему он дает 3 одинаковые записи?", вот как нам вам помочь без данных?

Comment: Добавил картинки

Comment: Вооот, видите, хоть кроха, но полезной информации есть. Только вы так и не удалили лишнее, а также не написали, что за фреймворк для работы с бд используется, предположу, что EF. И мне кажется сразу можно предположить проблему по последнему скрину. Что у вас является ключом в таблице? Оно уникально? Вот к примеру [первая ссылка гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3111144/6808809), или [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634113/6808809), вы смотрели?

Comment: Колючем сделал id identity,ну эти два поста которые вы скинули я просмотрел,во втором наиболее близка ситуация к моей

Comment: неактуально сам разорбался

Comment: Если нашли ответ, то стоит про него написать, помним, что SO это не форум, а ресурс, где сообщество собирает ценную информацию.

Comment: Ключ не там стоял